# iPhone brightness gets set to the lowest after restart

Tags: iphone, ios, display, restart, auto-brightness

Whenever I restart my iPhone, the brightness gets set to the lowest, so it is very dim. Then I have to adjust it back to around the middle, where I like it.

How do I stop this from happening?

I turn off my iPhone by holding the power button, then slide to turn off, then press and hold power button to turn on.

I have auto-brightness disabled. I'm using an iPhone 6 with iOS 11.2.5.

Comment: How do you restart your iPhone (regular restart/forced restart)?

Comment: Regular restart. Press and hold power button, slide to turn off. Press and hold power button to turn on.